# Как взять строку из ресурсов?

Tags: java, android

Есть ресурс в strings.xml

```
<string name="Rec1">Record1</string>
```

Есть строка

```
String s;
```

Хочу присвоить ей значение

```
s = R.string.Rec1;
```

ругается что это Int.
Как быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `R` хранит лишь `id` ресурсов. Это относится и к строкам.
Строку в данном случае можно получить при помощи метода `getString` класса `Context`.

```
String value = context.getString(R.string.value);
```

Если речь идёт об `Activity`, который наследуется от `Context`, то можно просто:

```
String value = getString(R.string.value);
```